# Can I link org src code to configuration sections using org-links or some other method?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, init

I would like to be able to list the packages that I am using up front so that they can be installed. In Org-mode, I'd like there to be a link next to each package name (or the package name itself to be a link) to take me to the section of my org-mode init file where the customization for that package is done.

For example, if I had something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes

(defvar package-list
  '(foo-mode
    bar-mode
    ....))
#+END_SRC
```

I could do something like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes

(defvar package-list
  '(foo-mode          ;; [[#foo-config]]
    bar-mode          ;; [[#bar-config]]
    ....))
#+END_SRC
```

Does anybody know how to make that happen?

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK you can only do the reverse: org mode link to code and not: code to org mode section. See http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html for org mode to code (line or ref) examples.